# I am trying to add a string into a list in python but get an error

Tags: python

I am trying to insert a string into a list in python but get this error listed below is my code:

```
import time 

mode = 0
Continue = 0

def startup():
    global mode
    mode = input("What Mode Do You Want To Select? (Read, Write, Code and Delete): ")
def cont():
    global Continue
    Continue = input("Do You Want To Continue? (Yes Or No): ")
    time.sleep(0.4)
    if Continue == "Yes":
        print("--------------------------------------------------- 
-------------------------")
    elif Continue == "No":
        print("Have A Good Day!")
    else:
        print("Error")
    
startup()
print("You Selected: " + mode)

cont()

Note_Book = ['o']

if mode == "Read":
    print("Your Note Contains: " + str(Note_Book))
elif mode == "Write":
    Point_Of_Insert = input("At What Point Do You Want To Insert? (Start At 0) ")
    word = input("What Do You Want To Write? ")
    Note_Book.insert(Point_Of_Insert, word)

^
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "placeholder", line 32, in module
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this? I am making a notes program with a code generator. If anyone has any ideas on how I could achieve this goal pleas include that in your comment.

Comment: `Point_Of_Insert` is a string.

Comment: Format the code or at least the traceback correctly and ensure that the traceback is complete.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to? @MichaelButscher

Comment: @JoaquinSacasa Copy and paste the traceback and format it as code (with the `{}` button).

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
import time 

mode = 0
Continue = 0

def startup():
    global mode
    mode = input("What Mode Do You Want To Select? (Read, Write, Code and Delete): ")
def cont():
    global Continue
    Continue = input("Do You Want To Continue? (Yes Or No): ")
    time.sleep(0.4)
    if Continue == "Yes":
        print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    elif Continue == "No":
        print("Have A Good Day!")
    else:
        print("Error")
    
startup()
print("You Selected: " + mode)

cont()

Note_Book = []

if mode == "Read":
    print("Your Note Contains: " + str(Note_Book))
elif mode == "Write":
    Point_Of_Insert = int(input("At What Point Do You Want To Insert? (Start At 0) "))
    word = str(input("What Do You Want To Write? "))
    Note_Book.insert(Point_Of_Insert, word)
    print(Note_Book)
```